# Remove elements when getting the "missing element" error

Tags: r, list, matrix, tidyverse

I have a data set `df` that I subset into two list `int1` and `int2`. Each one of the elements in this list represents a 10-day period for single individual (e.g., the first three elements in `int1` represent three different 10-day periods for `ID` "A"). `int2` is a bit different because it only has one 10-day period for `ID` "A" and "B". This is because the data for `month` 4 only has one 10-day period.

I also have a list `l1` that contains two matrices.

Setting up the example data:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2011"), dmy("10-04-2011"), by = "days"), 100)
ID <- rep(c("A","B"), 100)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$julian <- yday(df$date)
df$month <- month(df$date)

int1 <- df %>%
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(month == "1") %>% 
  group_split()

int2 <- df %>%
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(month == "4") %>% 
  group_split()


m1 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m2 <- matrix(20:28, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
l1 <- list(m1, m2)
```

In the following code, I use the objects that I have created above. `g1` is created as a sequence that is used in `lstMat`.

`f1` is a function that does a number of calculations between `int1` and `int2` is also created to be used in `lstMat`.

```
g1 <- rep(seq_along(l1), sapply(l1, nrow))

# Function to calculate the number of julian dates between the first date in the
# first interval and the first date of the second interval
f1 <- function(.int1, .int2) {
  t(outer(seq_along(.int1), seq_along(.int2),
          FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j) {
            min(.int1[[i]]$jDate) -
              min(.int2[[j]]$jDate)
          })
  ))
}
g1 <- rep(seq_along(l1), sapply(l1, nrow))

# Function to calculate the number of julian dates between the first date in the
# first interval and the first date of the second interval
f1 <- function(.int1, .int2) {
  t(outer(seq_along(.int1), seq_along(.int2),
          FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j) {
            min(.int1[[i]]$jDate) -
              min(.int2[[j]]$jDate)
          })
  ))
}
```

This is the section of my script that I have been getting an error on.

```
lstMat <- purrr::map2(split(int1[seq_len(length(g1))], g1), 
                      split(int2[seq_len(length(g1))], g1), f1)
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in `stop_subscript()`:
! Can't subset elements that don't exist.
x Locations 3, 4, 5, and 6 don't exist.
i There are only 2 elements.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I think the error is occuring due to the mismatch in length between `g1` and `int2` when trying to create the `lstMat` object. I was wondering how I could modify the code to remove those missing elements from `g1` when I try to split `int2` based on the `g1` when running `lstMat`.

Comment: I added "int2[[3]] <- int2[[4]] <- int2[[5]] <- int2[[6]] <- int2[[2]][0,]" after int2 is defined to just see what you were going for, but I'm not sure the result is what you're looking for...

Comment: Thank you for attempting it! The result is similar to what I would want, except the values in the matrices aren't `NaN`s. It did bypass the error, but I was thinking that instead of adding elements to `int2` I would remove the extra elements in `g1` in that particular instance in `lstMat`.

Comment: Can you add to the example you've posted above to share what you would expect/hope the result to be? That might help you find someone who can help you.